# XSLT: make element name an attribute while renaming

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to utilize XSLT to translate this weather stream (truncated) into something usable by one of our information display systems. This is the first time I've worked with XSLT, so I don't know where to start. 
It appears that I need to convert each element name into an attribute of itself, while renaming the element, but I can't seem to find any examples of this type of transformation. If anyone knows of any examples I could look at that would be helpful.

Current input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<current_observation version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.weather.gov/view/current_observation.xsd">
    <credit>NOAA's National Weather Service</credit>
    <credit_URL>http://weather.gov/</credit_URL>
    <image>
        <url>http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</url>
        <title>NOAA's National Weather Service</title>
        <link>http://weather.gov</link>
    </image>
    <suggested_pickup>15 minutes after the hour</suggested_pickup>
    <suggested_pickup_period>60</suggested_pickup_period>
    <location>Kansas City International Airport, MO</location>
    <station_id>KMCI</station_id>
    <latitude>39.3</latitude>
    <longitude>-94.73</longitude>
</current_observation>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<dataitems>
    <dataitem name="credit">NOAA's National Weather Service</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="credit_URL">http://weather.gov/</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="suggested_pickup">15 minutes after the hour</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="suggested_pickup_period">60</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="location">Kansas City International Airport, MO</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="station_id">KMCI</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="latitude">39.3</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="longitude">-94.73</dataitem>
</dataitems>
```

Comment: You should at least attempt to write some code. As is this looks like you are asking for a free developer to do your work for you.

Comment: I apologize if it seemed like I wanted someone to give me an finished answer.. I was only asking for a point in the right direction to a similar conversion, or if there is a specific name for this I could use to search on. All of the examples I've found deal with renaming elements, but not making the old name part of the new attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>


<!-- copy all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- replace root element -->
<xsl:template match="current_observation">
    <dataitems><xsl:apply-templates/></dataitems>
</xsl:template>

<!-- transformation for the rest of nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="credit|credit_URL|suggested_pickup|suggested_pickup_period|location|station_id|latitude|longitude">
    <dataitem name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></dataitem>
</xsl:template>

<!-- delete unwanted element -->
 <xsl:template match="image"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<dataitems>
    <dataitem name="credit">NOAA's National Weather Service</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="credit_URL">http://weather.gov/</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="suggested_pickup">15 minutes after the hour</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="suggested_pickup_period">60</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="location">Kansas City International Airport, MO</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="station_id">KMCI</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="latitude">39.3</dataitem>
    <dataitem name="longitude">-94.73</dataitem>
</dataitems>
```